# Output lines while deleting specific characters in Python

Tags: python

I have a text file which consists of lines of the following general format:

```
5.1: 23
10.145: 34
```

etc.

I need Python code that outputs the content of each line such that the characters after the period `.` and before the colon `:` are deleted.

That is, it would output the above as

```
5: 23
10: 34
```

So far I have the following code that I have been using for similar edits to the text file:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    with open("newfile.txt", "w") as output: 
        for line in f:
             output.write(line[1:])
```

which I used to delete the first character of each line. How can I do what I need here?

Comment: Have you searched for something like "split string in Python"?

Comment: I have not; let me give that a try.

Comment: Ok, I tried this:

with open("lessagony.txt", "r") as f:

    with open("crosstest.txt", "w") as output: 

        for line in f:

                 

                 word = line.split('.')

                 word = line.split(':')

                 myString = ''

                 myString.join(word)

                 output.write(myString)

but it outputs an empty file.

Comment: You can update what you have tried in your post :-)

Comment: But only if it doesn't invalidate existing answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try regular expressions:

```
import re
txt="10.145: 34"
re.sub("\.\d+:",":",txt)
```

- ".\d+:" matches period, one or more digits after the period and colon.
- ":" this replaces the match.

Here is the full program.

```
import re
import os, sys

output_file_name = 'results.txt'
if not os.path.exists(output_file_name):
    out = open(output_file_name, 'w+')       
else:
    print('File already exists!')
    sys.exit()

with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        new_line = re.sub("\.\d+:",":",line)
        print(new_line, end="") #this will print to screen
        out.write(new_line) #this will write to output file
```

Comment: This worked well, thank you - the output file now reads with two colons instead of one, but I think I can fix that on my own. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible you made a typo? At my computer it prints single colon. I used Python 3.9.5. I am not a Python expert. Good luck.

Comment: I did have a typo. Works fine!

Comment: If you want to try for fun, what @mkrieger1 suggested, you could split at at '.' and assign left and right columns to two variables. Then split the right column from the first split again at ':', and assign the left and right columns to new variables. Finally take the relevant parts from first and second splits and concatenate them as leftCol1+ ":" + rightCol2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions for this:

Example general code:

```
import re

x = ['5.1: 23', '10.145: 34']


def my_sub(x, delete_string = "\..*:", replacement = ":"):
    return re.sub(delete_string, replacement , x)


list(map(my_sub, x))
```

For your specific case:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    with open("newfile.txt", "w") as output: 
        for line in f:
            output.write(my_sub(line))
```

Explaining the regex:

- \. is escaping the special character '.' to make it the normal character '.'
- '.' is the special character wildcard
- '*' means match as many as you can
- ':' we go until we hit this